# How the author name could be made italic in citation using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I'm using this code:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{ALEXANDER1977apl,
    Address = {USA},
    Author = {Alexander, Christopher and Ishikawa, Sara and Silverstein, Murray},
    Date-Added = {2010-02-24 11:14:54 +1100},
    Date-Modified = {2010-06-01 12:10:48 +1000},
    Publisher = {{Oxford University Press}},
    Title = {{A Pattern Language: Towns, Buildings, Construction}},
    Year = {1977}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[indexing=cite,style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear,sorting=none,maxnames=1]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCite{%
  %\let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}
\makeatother
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite[pp 45]{ALEXANDER1977apl}
\end{document}
```

I wonder how I could change appearence of my citation so Author name will be italic?

*Alexander* et al. [1977, pp 45]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are able to change the formatting of *all* last names that appear in your citations

```
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

...and then reset the formatting before `\printbibliography` so that the names appear in upright font in the bibliography.  Your MWE would become:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{ALEXANDER1977apl,
    Address = {USA},
    Author = {Alexander, Christopher and Ishikawa, Sara and Silverstein, Murray},
    Date-Added = {2010-02-24 11:14:54 +1100},
    Date-Modified = {2010-06-01 12:10:48 +1000},
    Publisher = {{Oxford University Press}},
    Title = {{A Pattern Language: Towns, Buildings, Construction}},
    Year = {1977}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,indexing=cite,style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear,sorting=none,maxnames=1]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}
\makeatother
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

% Renew formatting of the last name to add emphasis
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}
% Revert formatting of the last name for bibliography
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{#1}}

\begin{document}


\noindent Text citation: \textcite[pp 45]{ALEXANDER1977apl}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

End result:
[image: citation and bibliography]

Comment: +1 I would recommend using `\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{#1}}` in the preamble instead of switching back via `\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{#1}` before `\printbibliography` though, it seems cleaner to me. (Also I would issue `\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}` in the preamble and not the document body.) Alternatively, one could use `\AtEveryCite{\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}}` in the preamble.

Comment: Good suggestions. I have updated with these in mind.  It makes sense to keep all the formatting commands together.

Answer (score 0):

For me neither `\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{#1}}` nor renewing the command before `\printbibliography` worked and I ended up with italic Last names in the Bibliography as well. What helped was substituting `\mkbibnamelast` with `\mkbibnamefamily` in both `\renewcommand`(s). I'm using `biblatex`.

Can't comment yet, unfortunately.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! - Could add compilable code?(or should it be only a comment)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864